# add to react array that is stored in state by function outside of the class

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**How can i pass this.state.data to a function outside a react.CreateClass**

I have a react piece of code that i want to optimize by adding an array element to a JavaScript object that is created from a JSON array.

The data is retrieved then bound using `this.setState({data: data})` i want to then pass this array/state into an external function to compare data. This all works, however i am now trying to add a new key and value onto the array so that in the render function the class will change.

As the code below shows i am trying to pass this.state.data to the function, but i get the error `state.push` is not a function.

```
import React from 'react';
    var oldData = null;
    var Soccer = React.createClass({
       getInitialState: function() {
            return {
            data: null
            };
        },
        componentDidMount: function() {
            fetch('./test.json').then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({data: data});
                checkData(data, oldData, this.state.data);
                oldData = data; 
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
        },
        render: function() {
                <div className={"someClass " + this.state.data.theKey}>
                </div>
                );
            }
        }
    });
    function checkData(newData, oldData, state) {
      if(oldData != null && newData != null){
        for(let key in newData.something){
            var theKey = "someKey";
            var obj = {};
            if(newData < oldData){
                obj[theKey] = "red";

            }else{
                obj[theKey] = "";
            }
            state.push(obj);
        }
        console.log(state);
      }
    }
    export default Soccer;
```

Comment: is your json data an array?

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
checkData(data, oldData, this.state);
```

instead of

```
checkData(data, oldData, this.state.data);
```

work?

Comment: From the react docs:
"Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable."

It may be possible to pass this.setState as a higher order function and call that from within the external function. As the others said .push won't work on an object.

Answer (score 0):

this.setState({data: "aaa"}). this function (this.setState) is not set the data to "aaa" immediately.  So the first called of componentDidMount, this.state.data is null

the react doc says: "setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value."

[react setState doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse, yes i know that why i put in the `oldData != null && newData != null` function as the first 2 times around the code fires there is null data.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't  see it. Sorry for not helping you。

Answer (score 0):

The `state` variable is an object literal (`{}`), not an array literal (`[]`), hence no `push()` function exists as only array literals have the `push()` function.

There is a more fundamental issue with the code you have posted which is, when you modify the state variable in the `checkData` function, React will not re-render the `Soccer` component (which I assume you are expecting to happen). React only re-renders on `setState()` or `forceUpdate()` commands.

So you could either:

1. Pass references to those functions to checkData (not recommended), or
2. Structure your `checkData` function to return a result which the component could utilise to modify the UI (via. state changes or otherwise)

Comment: Thanks for the response, the code re-renders as i have a  setInterval function, i just didn't put it in as i didn't want to bloat. The 2nd second makes sense, but i see a problem in making in scale, as i have around 80+ values and key-pairs to check, that all need to be displayed.

Comment: To keep it in its current form, then you would direct modify the state variable - you wouldn't need the `obj` variable defined, i.e,
`state[theKey] = "red";`